# Java JDBC connection with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to connect with SQLite database , with help from the following link http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/ on my Linux PC.

Everything works when I tried via command line (as per from that link). Since my complete project is plugged with Eclipse , I tried add the `sqlite-jdbc-3.5.7.jar` to the eclipse Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path.

but when I tried to run the application I get the following error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ibex/classgen/CGConst .`

Can somebody please help to fix this issue?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126019/where-should-i-put-an-external-jar-file-in-my-eclipse-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class org/ibex/classgen/CGConst doesn't exist in the sqlite-jdbc-3.5.7.jar. 
Check the project to be sure about the classpath configurations (maybe versions conflicts) and imports in the class when you use the database conection.